# Javascript DOM image to canvas

Tags: javascript, image, html, canvas, cross-domain

I need to create a canvas element from a previously loaded image in the DOM. How I can do this with javascript?

The source of my images are on another server. Therefore I have Cross domain problems...

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Did you go through the [canvas image tutorial on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Tutorial/Using_images)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have created [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E6SNu/1/) that shows how to load images, cross domain and then display on canvas..

```
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var imageObj = new Image();

    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function(){
        context.drawImage(img, 69, 50);

    }
    img.src="http://indianautosblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/2014-Ferrari-F150-Enzo-successor-rendered.jpeg";
```

This JS shows how to load an image from another site..

Comment: Yes, but this will not "taint" the canvas? Can i use the image that i have already loaded in the DOM ? I need to call getImageData() after is loaded. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand your question. If your image is already on the DOM then why are you facing cross domain issues? Also getImageData() is a function referenced where?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-images/)
Just pass `drawImage` the image object.

Comment: Thanks for the aswer. I have the same problem that in the other answer. I can't set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in the image server, so the canvas get tainted. And i can't use getImageData() . Thanks !